# Magento 2.3.x: Display address field on registration form?

Tags: magento2.3

I'm looking for a way to display address fields on the customer registration form. In previous versions of Magento 2, I was able to add them using the below snippet in the **customer_account_create.xml** file:

```
<argument name="show.address.fields" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
```

Since the release of Magento 2.3.1, this snippet doesn't seem to have any impact, has anyone come across how to now achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme-name/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account_create.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_form_register">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="show_address_fields" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

This works correctly in `Magento ver. 2.3.4`